# Xcode 12 "show library" command no longer shows possible views to be added

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I work on a SwiftUI iOS App
I use Version 12.4 (12D4e) of Xcode, and I have no longer the opportunity to pick up the possible "View" types to add in my views as before with the "Show Library" command (i.e. the "+" button, first one on top right)
Only the "Snippets", "Media" and "Color" buttons are visible
How could I restore the complete list of possibilities ?
Thanks for your help

PS: I tried to stop Xcode and to launch it again, this does not fix the issue...

Comment: Try `Shift + CMD + L`

Comment: Is the SwiftUI preview canvas open? Having the canvas open was the only way for me to access the SwiftUI Views library in Xcode 12.5.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but in my case this was really an issue solved by restarting the Mac.

Answer (score -1):

The missing "Views" and "Modifiers" that were lacking in "Show Library" command came back after restarting my Mac...
So closing and launching Xcode was not sufficient.
Sorry to have disturb people for so little !